# onclick on a hyperlink not running javascript in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

My Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 //<![CDATA[
function showAnswer()
{
  alert('Answer');
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');
if (els.style.display != 'inline')
    els.style.display = 'inline';
} 
}

     //]]>
</script>
```

Where answer is a class name on page for p tag which is initially hidden by the following code:

```
 .answer { display:none; }
```

This is code for calling showAnswer which is not working...

```
 <div class='show_hide_answers'>
        <a href='#' onclick='showAnswer();'>Show Answer</a>
 </div>
```

Clicking on Show answer does nothing. Even it is not showing alert means javascript is not running. Please help me solve this problem.
See this page for more details (this is the code for this page)

http://www.technodoze.com/2012/09/the-idea-that-light-is-em-wave-was.html

Thanks in advance if you could help me plz...

Note: I have tried all these:

```
<a href='#' onclick='showAnswer()'>Show Answer</a>

<a href='#' onclick='javascript:showAnswer();'>Show Answer</a>

<a href='#' onclick='javascript:return showAnswer();'>Show Answer</a>
```

No one is working.

Comment: you need to add { braket after `if (els.style.display != 'inline')
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) instead of a single `Node`. Thus, you need to iterate over the resulting `NodeList`:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var el = eles[i];
  if (el.style.display != 'inline') {
    el.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem is not this.. I had the same code before which you have mentioned. My real problem is that javascript is not being execeuted at **all**. Tell me error in my javascript executing code.

Comment: Thanks to YOU, the solution to my problem was which both of you mentioned... This really is a great forum!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you debug javascript, please use your console, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }". there is a `{` missing after the if.

also [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) does not return a single element but a set of elements (notice the getElement_*s*_)

Comment: Thanks to YOU, the solution to my problem was which both of you mentioned... This really is a great forum!!!